# MYSQL Sum distinct values after left join

Tags: mysql, select, sum, left-join

I have these tables

```
/*OrderRows*/

order_id | row_id | article | quantity
    1    |    1   |   pen   |   10
    1    |    2   |scissors |   7
    2    |    3   |  book   |   5 
    3    |    4   |  pen    |   5 

/*Shipments*/

shipment_id | row_id   | quantity_shipped
    1       |     1    |         3
    2       |     1    |         4
    3       |     1    |         3
    4       |     2    |         7
    5       |     3    |         5
    6       |     4    |         5
```

And I need to generate a report to check if an order has been entirely shipped

I wish to use left join instead of subquerys (just to check: is it more efficient?)

If I ask

```
SELECT
    OrderRows.order_id,
    sum(OrderRows.quantity) as ordered,
    sum(Shipments.quantity_shipped) as shipped
FROM
    Orders
LEFT JOIN Shipments ON OrderRows.row_id = Shipments.row_id
GROUP BY OrderRows.order_id
```

I obviously obtain

```
order_id | orderered | shipped
    1    |    27    |   17
    2    |    5     |   5
    3    |    5     |   5
```

That's because making left join replicates me the Orders.quantity three times 
 for order_id = 1 (because for order_id = 1 there are 3 shipments)

how can I obtain this without using a subquery?

```
order_id | orderered | shipped
    1    |    17    |   17
    2    |    5     |   5
    3    |    5     |   5
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well if ordered/quantity is a property of `order_id` then simply select it and `group by`

```
SELECT
    Orders.order_id,
    Orders.quantity as ordered,
    sum(Shipments.quantity_shipped) as shipped
FROM
    Orders
LEFT JOIN Shipments ON Orders.order_id = Shipments.order_id
GROUP BY Orders.order_id,orders.quantity
```

Comment: Ha! You answered while I was making this: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/5ce8e/3

Comment: Your answer was right, but I semplified too much my code, these are Order rows, not just orders, so if I group by orders.quantity I obtain a duplicated row in the resultset. I updated my question to show this. Sorry man

Comment: Then your data model is wrong because you have multiple rows for the same order! If you want to persist with that knowing the quantity is the same on all rows, simply select MAX not sum.

Comment: The quantity is not the same on all rows, it is tied to the quantity of a specific article on that order, the fact that for order_id = 1 there are two rows with quantity = 10 it's just a case. I'm editing it in order to not generating confusion